# Sum object in a column between an interval defined by another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
  df
       A B
 [1,]  1 4
 [2,]  2 3
 [3,]  3 5
 [4,]  4 7
 [5,]  5 5
 [6,]  6 7
 [7,]  7 4
 [8,]  8 7
 [9,]  9 3
[10,] 10 7
```

I need to sum the numbers in column B that fall between a certain interval defined by column A. For example sum the value in B between A≥1 and A<3.

I'm trying to use this:

```
> sum(which(df$B[df$A>=1] & df$B[df$A<3]))
```

but it does not give me what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
with(my.df, sum(my.df[A >= 1 & A < 3, "B"]))
```

*EDIT*

Chase challenged me to explain away the code at hand. When reading R code, it's best to read from inwards out. Here we go.

`my.df` is a data.frame (think Excel sheet) with columns `A` and `B`. Square brackets `[]` are used to subset *anything* from this object like so: `[rows, columns]`. For example, `[1, ]` would return the entire first row, and if you add a column number (or column name), you get value in first row in that column (e.g. `[1, 2]`, where you would get value in the first row of the second column).
We will now subset rows in `my.df` with `A >= 1 & A < 3`. What we're saying here is we want to see those rows that have values in `A` bigger or equal to 1 and smaller than 3. This will give us all rows that satisfy this criterion. If we add `, "B"` it means we want to select column `B`. Since we already subsetted the result to contain only rows that fit the above criterion, by entering column name `B` we get values only in the column. Once you have those values from column `B` you sum them using `sum()`.
Use of `with` function is there to make our life easier. If we hadn't used that, we would be forced to call columns by their full name `my.df$A` and `my.df$B`.

Comment: even better: `with(my.df, sum(B[ A >= 1 & A < 3 ] ) )`

Comment: There's truly 1001 ways to skin a cat. Thanks for contributing (not to skinning of cats)!

Answer (score 2):

Another option using the select parameter from subset achieves identical results. : `sum(subset(dat, A < 3 & A >= 1, select = "B"))`

Roman's answer is faster, but arguably not as easy to deparse to the non R-expert. Depending on your audience (i.e. sharing script with colleagues) and performance constraints, one may be preferred to the other.

```
> system.time(replicate(100,with(dat, sum(dat[A >= 1 & A < 3, "B"]))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.008 
> system.time(replicate(100, sum(subset(dat, A < 3 & A >= 1, select = "B"))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.041   0.000   0.041
```

Comment: I take that challange (of deparsing to non-R user)!